# Find colum with certain text and use entire column as a range in index match

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two worksheets with +5000 rows and I need to copy pre postings from Sheet1 to Sheet2 with index match.

I want to activate certain column with a certain text and use that column as a range in my index match formula.

Currently my code requires that each user has their columns arranged same order as mine. As u can imagine, this is very risky solution and increases risk of faulty posting.

Next my current code:

```
Sub search()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim col As Integer

col = 1

Do Until Cells(1, col) = "Cust.Order ID"
col = col + 1
Loop
Columns(col).Select



Range("AY2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!C[110],MATCH(" & col & ",Sheet2!C[-50],0))="""","""",INDEX(Sheet2!C[110],MATCH( " & col & ",Sheet2!C[-50],0)))"
    Range("AY3").Select
End Sub
```

This one returns blanks as blanks which is necessary.
But now this code shows that " & col & " is 41 (as the column is AO) when it should use this columns values. Those values are purchase order numbers for example 65875.

Hopefully u guys can help me and thank u in advance.

Comment: with `MATCH(" & col & ",Sheet2!C[-50],0)` you are matching a number in a column.  So if `Cust.Order ID` is found in column E then you are trying to find `5` in the referenced column, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is the actual formula you think you want in the cell?  So you want to fill column AY with the formula?

Comment: Hey Scott and thank you for your comments!

This is the formula I actually want:

=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!FE:FE;MATCH('Sheet1'!AO:AO;Sheet2!A:A;0))="";"";INDEX(Sheet2!FE:FE;MATCH('Sheet1'!AO:AO;Sheet2!A:A;0)))

Comment: AO column is the column Im trying to "find" with variable. In some cases the customer order column might be different than in this case.

Comment: `MATCH('Sheet1'!AO:AO;Sheet2!A:A;0)` is not proper format for match.  `'Sheet1'!AO:AO` should be a single cell that references the cell in AO on that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
Sub search()
Dim col As Long
Dim lr As Long
col = 0
'Avoid .Select
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Find Column
    On Error Resume Next
    col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Cust.Order ID", .Range("1:1"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'If column not found return message and get out
    If col = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Column not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Find Last row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    'Fill full range with formula at once
    .Range(.Cells(2, "AY"), .Cells(lr, "Ay")).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!C[110],MATCH(RC" & col & ",Sheet2!C[-50],0))="""","""",INDEX(Sheet2!C[110],MATCH(RC" & col & ",Sheet2!C[-50],0)))"
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott! This code did excatly what I wanted! This was awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think that single formula should do the job, vba is not necessary.

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!FE1:FE100,MATCH(AO2,Sheet2!A:A,0), MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0))="‌​","",INDEX(Sheet2!FE‌​1:FE100,MATCH(AO2,Sheet2!A‌​:(a),0),MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0)))
```

Replace commas with ; if your excel needs it. Check, if lookup value for MATCH is in right column, I am not sure if I guessed correctly.

EDIT:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!A1:FE100,MATCH(AO2,Sheet2!A:A,0), MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0))="‌​","",INDEX(Sheet2!A​1:FE100,MATCH(AO2,Sheet2!A‌​:(a),0),MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0)))
```

asuming that the range with data is within A1:FE100

Comment: This will throw an error anytime `MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0)` is greater than 1.  You only have a single column in the index, you cannot refer to a greater column number than the number of columns in the INDEX.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are absolutely right. The first argument of INDEX should be corrected. Still, I don't think VBA is needed here.

Comment: Not not the first argument of the index, but the first argument of the MATCH:

Comment: `INDEX(Sheet2!FE:FE,MATCH(INDEX(A:FE,Row(),MATCH("Cust.Order ID", Sheet2!1:1,0)),Sheet2!A:A,0))`